# Can I prevent loading some HTML body and head in PWA when javascript is enabled?

Tags: seo, javascript, search-engine-indexing, crawlable-ajax

We have restricted resource and we can not use server side technology in our website.We are using PWA technology.What is our solution to pages indexed correctly in Google?

Can we load some head tags and body tags when js in disabled and prevent loading those tags when js in enabled?

I read the John guide:
https://plus.google.com/u/1/+JohnMueller/posts/LT4fU7kFB8W
But its not clear what we can do when js is disabled and when js is enabled?

And also there is a contradiction to John post in this link:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40349?hl=en

Google said test you pages with js-less browser and check your site accessible and renderable without js!

Finally what should we do?

Comment: Err? you can load JS and CSS using JavaScript, therefore yes you can control what is loaded with JS and when it's not. For CSS with disabled Javascript, you can use a css `.no-js` the approach, also, confused why you've used SEO tag on this question since Google does not reward sites for non-js compliance.

Comment: Don't build a site completely with JavaScript if you want search engine rankings.  Google is getting somewhat better at reading them, but there are huge problems getting them correctly indexed.   Other search engines are far worse than Google.